# Problem with "reserved space" in Highchart's Basic Bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We're creating a "basic bar" graph with data at `0`. By default, Highchart reserves an empty space for this data. We compare 100 lines. Half of them represent data at 0. So half the space is empty.

How do we get around this rule?

Comment: Use `null` instead of `0` in data

Comment: Hi @JGLectra, Is this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4716/ presents your problem? Do you want to show the values in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4719/ ?